# merging specific object values from array into separated array

Tags: javascript

I have this array of persons

```
personsList = [
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
]
```

in every object inside there more details beside `cities` but I want to make an array with all the cities inside - unique. so the result will be
`['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

I tried doing something like

```
const allCities = personsList.map(p => p.cities)
```

but then I got an array of arrays, what is the best approach for this one ? thanks.

Comment: p.cities is also array inner map function then use filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `array#map` all cities and then concat them into one array. Then using `Set` you can get the unique city.

```js
const personsList = [ {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']}, {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']}, {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']}, {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']} ],
      uniqueCity = Array.from(new Set([].concat(...personsList.map(({cities}) => cities))));
console.log(uniqueCity);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply @Hassan, how do I run `trim()` on each city ?

Comment: Then you can use `array#map`. `uniqueCity.map(city => city.trim());`

Comment: but then I'll have duplicate between `A` and `A ` in the final array

Answer (score 2):

You can try following using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var personsList = [
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
]
 
// cities will have all the cities with duplicates
const allCities = personsList.reduce((a,c) => [...a, ...c.cities], []);
// create set from array - removes duplicate and then create array back from set
console.log(Array.from(new Set(allCities)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use directly a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting unique values.

```js
var personsList = [{ cities: ['A', 'B', 'C'] }, { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C'] }, { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C'] }, { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] }],
    unique = Array.from(
        personsList.reduce(
            (s, { cities }) => cities.reduce((t, c) => t.add(c), s),
            new Set
        )
    );

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: `var` isn't technically deprecated, but I definitely think it should be avoided in all modern JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the effect that you are looking for, by using set you guarantee yourself that there are only unique elements.

```js
let personsList = [
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C']},
  {cities: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
]
const allCities = personsList.reduce((acc,e) => {
  e.cities.map(x=>{
  acc.add(x)
  })
  return acc
}, new Set())
console.log(Array.from(allCities))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const personsList = [
  { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C'] },
  { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C'] },
  { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C'] },
  { cities: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] }
];
const allCities = [...new Set([].concat(...personsList.map(({ cities }) => cities)))];
console.log(allCities);
```